# Check if location is within a certain distance of a set of other locations using R

Tags: r, match, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I am still new to R and a first time poster here. I tried to follow the rules as much as possible, but please let me know if I missed something or could do things better.

What I am trying to do is to match a set of places (POI's) with a set of stop locations of journeys. The locations of both sets are in latitudinal/longitudinal coordinates. If a journey location is within the radius of a POI (POI$rad), the name of the POI should be returned (POI$station).

I got this so far:

```
station <- c("a", "b", "c")
lat <- c(47.61870, 47.61422, 47.60603)
lng <- c(-122.34414, -122.32062, -122.32410)
rad <- c(0.075, 0.075, 0.175)
POI <- as.data.frame(list(station=station, lat=lat, lng=lng, rad=rad), 
       row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

journeynr <- c(1:6)
lat <- c(47.60643, 47.61013, 47.61855, 47.61855, 47.61432,47.61408)
lng <- c(-122.32404, -122.33355, -122.33263, -122.34437, -122.32082, -122.31914)
journey <- as.data.frame(list(journeynr=journeynr, lat=lat, lng=lng), 
           row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

earth.dist <- function (long1, lat1, long2, lat2)
{
  rad <- pi/180
  a1 <- lat1 * rad
  a2 <- long1 * rad
  b1 <- lat2 * rad
  b2 <- long2 * rad
  dlon <- b2 - a2
  dlat <- b1 - a1
  a <- (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(a1) * cos(b1) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
  c <- 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  R <- 6378.145
  d <- (R * c)
  return(d)
}

journey$test <- ifelse(earth.dist(journey$lat, journey$lng, 
                POI$lat, POI$lng) <= POI$rad, POI$station ,NA)
```

This doesn't really do what I want, because I think this compares row 1 of 'journey' with row 1 of 'POI', row 2 of 'journey' with row 2 of 'POI', etc. If I reduce POI to a single row by adding:

```
POI <- subset(POI, POI$station =="c")
```

Right before the last line, it does seem to work correctly. Unfortunately, only for that one POI. What I think I want is that row 1 of 'journey' gets compared with ALL rows of 'POI'.

Would this indeed be the right way to do this?
If so, what am I doing wrong?
If not ... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `outer` function may be helpful: `outer(1:nrow(journey),1:nrow(POI),function(x,y) earth.dist(journey$lat[x], journey$lng[x], POI$lat[y], POI$lng[y]))` will call `earth.dist` for every `journey` against any `POI`.

Comment: you could use the `apply` function to `apply` your ifelse to each row of `journey`: `t(apply(journey,1,function(x) {ifelse(earth.dist(x[2], x[3],POI$lat, POI$lng) <= POI$rad, POI$station ,NA)}))`

Comment: Just for clarity, either of the above will work, but watch the order of arguments -- the `earth.dist` function as defined in the question goes `lng` then `lat` - so using @NicE solution, you'll want: `t(apply(journey,1,function(x) {ifelse(earth.dist(x[3], x[2],POI$lng, POI$lat) <= POI$rad, POI$station ,NA)}))`

Comment: thanks for catching that, the OP might have it wrong in his post as well, didn't check the math @roger you might also want to look at the `geosphere` package, it has a few functions to calculate distance

Comment: Thanks all, for your help. I indeed switched the order of `lat` and `lng`, thanks @JasonAizkalns. I've tried the `apply` approach, but it results in an 18 row `journey` table where the first 6 rows are normal with results for row 1 of `POI`, rows 7-12 with results for row 2 of `POI` and rows 13-18 with results for row 3 of `POI`. I would like for the results to be combined in the first 6 rows of `journey`. Is this possible? Also, good tip on that `geosphere` package @NicE, I'll be sure to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this, want you were looking for?

```
d <- outer(1:nrow(journey), 1:nrow(POI), 
       FUN=function(i, j) 
          earth.dist(journey[i,"lng"], journey[i,"lat"], 
                POI[j,"lng"], POI[j, "lat"]))

apply(apply(d, 1, "-", POI$rad) < 0, 2, function(x) POI$station[x])
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you (and the others too of course) for helping. Now to figure out how it works .. ;)